# The predictive distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian

I'm currently studying a bit of Bayesian statistics, and I got my self a bit stuck on the following result regarding the predictive distribution for $\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X = x}$.

My book states
$$
f(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\theta\in\Omega} f(\mathbf{y},\theta|\mathbf{x})d\theta
= \int_{\theta\in\Omega} f(\mathbf{y}|\theta, \mathbf{x}) f(\theta|\mathbf{x})d\theta
= \int_{\theta\in\Omega} f(\mathbf{y}|\theta) f(\theta|\mathbf{x})d\theta
$$

I'm unsure how we get
$$
f(\mathbf{y},\theta|\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y}|\theta, \mathbf{x}) f(\theta|\mathbf{x})
$$
I've attempted to use
$$
f(\mathbf{x_a},\mathbf{x_b}) = f_{\mathbf{x_b}|\mathbf{x_a}}(\mathbf{x_b}|\mathbf{x_a})f_\mathbf{x_a}(\mathbf{x_a})
$$
but unsuccessfully. I've also tried
$$
f(\mathbf{y},\theta) = f_{\mathbf{Y|\theta}}(\mathbf{y}|\theta)f(\theta)
$$
but in unsure how to make it all conditional on $\mathbf{X}$. So yeah, I'm tying knots on my self a bit. Additionally, I'm also unsure about the step $f(\mathbf{y}|\theta, \mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$. I'm guessing this is because $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are independent. So, we have $f(\mathbf{y}|\theta, \mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)f(\mathbf{x})$, why why is $f(\mathbf{x}) = 1$?

I'm sure this is quite straightforward, since they offered no explanation of this in the book, and I'm probably just confusing my self a bit. But, I lost the better part of an hour trying on it already, and I think I might be fixating on a wrong approach.

Comment: If $f(\mathbf{y},\theta) = f_{\mathbf{Y\mid \theta}}(\mathbf{y}\mid \theta)f(\theta)$ is OK, then conditioning all that on $\mathbf{x}$ to give $f_{\mathbf{Y\mid \theta, \mathbf{x}}}(\mathbf{y},\theta\mid \mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y} \mid\theta, \mathbf{x}) f(\theta\mid \mathbf{x})$ should also be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(y, \theta \mid x) = f(y \mid \theta, x) f(\theta, x)$ is a special case of $f(y,\theta) = f(y \mid \theta) f(\theta)$ where everything is conditional on $x$.  If this is still not convincing to you, just go back to the original equation $f(y, \theta \mid x) = f(y \mid \theta, x) f(\theta, x)$ and plug in $f(y, \theta \mid x) = f(y,\theta,x) / f(x)$ and $f(y \mid \theta, x) = f(y,\theta,x)/f(\theta, x)$ to explicitly verify this.

---

$f(y \mid \theta, x) = f(y \mid \theta)$ is not true in general, but is true if $x$ and $y$ are **conditionally independent given $\theta$**. In fact this equation is sometimes taken as the definition of conditional independence; an equivalent definition is $f(y,x \mid \theta) = f(y \mid \theta) f(x \mid \theta)$.

Comment: Thanks alot! I was going in the right direction with my attempt to use $f(\mathbf{x_a},\mathbf{x_b}) = f_{\mathbf{x_b}|\mathbf{x_a}}(\mathbf{x_b}|\mathbf{x_a})f_\mathbf{x_a}(\mathbf{x_a})$, however, I had "a moment" regarding the notation that your answer fully cleared up! so thanks for that :-D Basically, I treated $f(y | \theta, x)$ as a function of $y|\theta$ and $x$ as opposed to $y$ given $\theta, x$. Not my strongest moment haha. Again, thanks.